# Is it possible to make the following code faster?

Tags: python, numpy, theano, sympy

The provided code works perfectly fine, but I would like to make it more efficient (if possible).

My question is whether the array `np_b` can be generated more efficiently. In particular, is it possible to calculate the function `theano_f` on all elements of `np_a` via `theano_f(*np_a)` so that broadcasting(?) or vectorization(?) would be applied?

Note that I have simplified my real problem and that I have to generate `theano_f` using `theano_function` from some sympy function and the actual array `np_a` contains numerous elements.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.printing.theanocode import theano_function
import numpy as np

x,y,z = symbols('x y z')
sympy_f = x+y+z # a sympy-function which depends on 3 variables
theano_f = theano_function([x,y,z], [sympy_f]) # Theano-compiled function which depends on 3 scalars
np_a = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[-1,-2,0],[0,2,0]])
np_b = np.array([theano_f(*x) for x in np_a]) # The obtained four numbers 
#should be recorded into the numpy-array np_b
print(np_b)
```

Comment: `numpy.vectorize` at least it will avoid creating a list, then converting it to back to an array: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I still don't understand how to make it work. I have created a vectorized function `vectorized_f = np.vectorize(theano_f)`. However, `vectorized_f(*[1,1,1])` works fine, but `vectorized_f(np_a)` raises TypeError: Missing required input. So I think the whole problem is with unpacking the elements in `np_a`. Could you please show how to actually apply vectorization in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try [np.apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
>>> def my_func(a):
...     """Average first and last element of a 1-D array"""
...     return (a[0] + a[-1]) * 0.5
>>> b = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> np.apply_along_axis(my_func, 0, b)
array([ 4.,  5.,  6.])
>>> np.apply_along_axis(my_func, 1, b)
array([ 2.,  5.,  8.])
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` still iterates over the other dimensions of `b`.  It's a convenience, not a speed tool.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, when I try to call the function `np_b = np.apply_along_axis(theano_f, 1, np_a)` (I think this is what should I do in my situation), there is an error 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 0, got 1 with shape (3,).` Is any way to unpack elements of `np_a` in some smart way so that the function `theano_f` is calculated efficiently?

Comment: as hpaulj said, it's not really a speed tool, so it probably won't help. you can still try though. the error you posted means the dimension in which you're applying this to the array is wrong. try using apply_along_axis with the second argument (axis) set to 0 instead of 1.